# How to use google translator with flags in nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Reactjs and trying to integrate "google translator with flags",I have following code
which is working fine (html + javascript code) and giving me exactly output as i want but how can i use this
code in "nextjs/react" (index.js page)?

```
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Google Translation</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.5.0/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
<body>
   
        <div id="google_translate_element" style="display: none;"></div>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" onchange="translateLanguage(this.value);">
            <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> English' value="English">English</option>
            <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></span> French' value="French">French</option>
            <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-es"></span> Spanish' value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            This is just a table.
        </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false }, 'google_translate_element');
        }

        function translateLanguage(lang) {
            googleTranslateElementInit();
            var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
      //alert('value is ' +lang);
            
      if (!$frame.size()) {
                alert("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
                return false;
            }
            $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains(' + lang + ')').get(0).click();
            return false;
        }

        $(function(){
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried but giving me following error

```
"Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update answer:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  function translateLanguage(lang) {
    googleTranslateElementInit();
    const frame = document.getElementsByClassName("goog-te-menu-frame")[0];
    if (!frame) return;
    const items = frame.contentDocument.documentElement.querySelectorAll(
      ".goog-te-menu2-item"
    );
    items.forEach((element) => {
      if (lang == element.getElementsByTagName("span")[1].innerText)
        element.click();
    });
    return false;
  }

  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    if (!google) return;
    new (google.translate.TranslateElement)(
      {
        pageLanguage: "en",
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
        autoDisplay: false
      },
      "google_translate_element"
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = `https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit`;
    document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.childNodes[0]);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="google_translate_element" style={{ display: "none" }} />
      <CustomSelect onChange={translateLanguage} />
      <div>This is just a table.</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const CustomSelect = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState(LANGS[0]);
  const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useClickOutside(ref, () => setIsShow(false));
  return (
    <div className="w-24 cursor-pointer relative">
      <div onClick={() => setIsShow(true)} ref={ref}>
        <span className={`flag-icon ${lang.icon}`} /> {` ${lang.name}`}
      </div>
      <div
        className={`border border-b-0 absolute top-6 left-0 bg-white ${!isShow && "hidden"
          }`}
      >
        {LANGS.map((lang, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className="border-b"
            onClick={() => {
              setLang(lang);
              onChange(lang);
            }}
          >
            <span className={`flag-icon ${lang.icon}`} />
            {` ${lang.name}`}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const LANGS = [
  {
    name: "English",
    icon: "flag-icon-us"
  },
  {
    name: "French",
    icon: "flag-icon-fr"
  },
  { name: "Spanish", icon: "flag-icon-es" }
];

const useClickOutside = (ref, callback) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      callback(e);
    }
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  });
};
```

You can check in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-animation-in-nextjs-or-react-with-tailwind-css-forked-ifh3oy?file=/pages/index.js:0-2696)
[image]

Comment: it working but still showing same error and flags are not displaying

Comment: waiting for your reply

Comment: i'm checking...

Comment: @sky i have updated answer, no need to add script in _document.js. Your flag not appear because selectpicker not working in react so your data-content in option not working also. Im not sure how to add a flag div inside option, but you can try another ui/ux, which not use select

Comment: actually my main motive is to "display flag" with languages

Comment: i am getting following error " ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Optional chaining cannot appear in the callee of new expressions (25:18)
File was processed with these loaders "

Comment: @sky i'm creating a custom select with flag, please wait

Comment: okay sure, i am waiting

Comment: @sky have updated my answer, i used tailwind to style custom select [codesandbox](https://ifh3oy.sse.codesandbox.io/)

Comment: your demo link is not working , showing error, Please check

Comment: can we use "horizontal button" instead of "dropdown" ? if yes then how ?

Comment: i dont understand what horizontal button is?

Comment: your code is not working in my side, flags are not showing as well as translator also not working

Comment: Im not sure what happened with your site, please take a look in my codesandbox

Comment: you have to add cdn link of flag-icon-css to _document.js @sky

Comment: kindly share exact code of _document.js so i can check in my side

Comment: @sky you can see here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-animation-in-nextjs-or-react-with-tailwind-css-forked-ifh3oy?file=/pages/index.js)

Comment: should i download "tailwind.config.js" ?

Comment: I used tailwind for quickly style css, you can style select by normal class and css without tailwind. If you want to install tailwindcss, check here [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs)